# Extracting dataframe into a UTF-8 csv

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, dataframe

I have a dataframe call mydf with a column containing some Vietnamese characters. I would like to extract this dataframe into a csv file:

```
con = file("myFile.csv","w", encoding="utf8")
write.csv(mydf, con, row.names=FALSE)
close(con)
```

But when I open my extracted csv with the notepad the vietnamese characters got messed up.

Comment: By `notepad` you actually mean the Windows `notepad.exe`? AFAIK that requires a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (which you should absolutely not put in a proper UTF-8 file :)). Try using a different editor like Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your notepad is seeing that file as ASCII. See below pictures. Choose a proper [programmer's text editor](https://www.google.com.tr/search?num=100&safe=off&es_sm=122&q=programmer%27s%20text%20editor&oq=programmer%27s%20text%20editor).

```
s = c("aaşğiü", "ŞÇÖĞÜbb") 
df = data.frame(s) 

con = file("myFile.csv","w", encoding="utf8")
write.csv(df, con, row.names=FALSE)
close(con)
```

[image: UTF8]

[image: ASCII]

Comment: Thanks it works with your example but when i with try the following: s = c("aaşğiü", "Đối kháng"), I got "Ð<U+1ED1>i kháng" instead of "Đối kháng"

Comment: @user2741700 You are right. I am getting same result

Comment: Any idea on how I can solve that. Still couldn't find the solution. Thanks.